# Custom combo filter using boolean converter

Tags: silverlight, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics XamGrid, I have one Template Column which I bind to a boolean value, I then use a converter to display a string based on the value (e.g True = "Dog", False="Cat").

What I want is to be able to use a combobox in the filter and select Dog or Cat and it filter my grid...but I haven't got a clue where to start. I have to combobox setup as the custom filter with SelectionChanged event etc but don't know where to go from here.

Any advice or a point in the right direction would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the SelectionChanged event, depending on whether they selected Dog or Cat from the combobox you would add a filter programmatically to the column for true or false.
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/2012.2/CLR4.0/?page=xamGrid_Programmatically_Create_a_Filter.html

Make sure to use an EqualsOperand for the FilteringOperand property.  Also you can use a TextColumn instead of a TemplateColumn and use the TextColumn's ValueConverter to avoid creating your own templates.